# Fluid + Responsive OR Different Stylesheets for every screen resolution?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, fluid

I am building a wordpress theme which I am going to sell in a marketplace. What's the best choice, Fluid and Responsive (using css media queries) or make use of different stylesheets for every screen resolution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really a subjective question that can not really be awarded an answer.

Best practice is a single stylesheet, however a mobile first stylesheet could be used with a larger stylesheet containing some overriding styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a question that allows a correct answer but here's my 2p/

If you are making it for a commercial market you are likely to find more customers I would suggest - just look at the sales generated on [Themeforest](http://themeforest.net/) for the responsive themes.

Comment: McNab thanks a lot for your answer. I know how to design responsive layouts, I have done it many times in the past but there were made to be sold only once, one layout for each single client. Now I am going to sell it in a marketplace and I really don't know which method to pick! :)

Comment: Sorry Arg, I reread your post after I answered and realised that.  Have changed my answer accordingly!  Good luck, a good time to be producing responsive commercial themes.